# How to prevent a shrinkwrapped container's scrollbar from overlapping its content?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scrollbar, overflow

I have the following code:

```html
<div style="
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
 ">
  <div style="
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
 ">text here to occupy some width</div>
</div>
```

Which results in this:
[image]
The red box shrinkwraps the blue box, as expected, but the scrollbar overlaps the content, and I don't want that.

I need to achieve this:
[image]

How can this be done?

PS: I need this to work on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's important that the text is displayed in one line? (i.e. you need white-space: nowrap;)?

You could add a padding-right to the inner div with the same width as the scrollbar.

```html
<div style="
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
"><div style="
    height: 160px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 17px;
">text here to occupy some width</div></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if there is no scrollbar (I need to cover that case too)